# Getting 0 result from MySQL database , while my query and database name every thing is right

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, shortcode

I have prefixed the custom and deafaults tables of wordpress.
Also I have put data in tables but I'm getting result 0.
Connection to database is ok and working

```
$sql = "SELECT u_name, u_email FROM jobify_user";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows> 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        return "id: " . $row["u_name"]. "name:".$row["u_email"].  "                  <br>";
    }
} 
else {
    return "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering so the prefix is "jobify" and you're using wordpress tables, and according to https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_users, the table_name must be jobify_users, and columns must be user_name and user_email.

So, your query must surely be :

```
    $sql = "SELECT user_name, user_email FROM jobify_users";
```

Comment: thanks but that table i have created by my self , its name is user